# Python pandas series access by index: Data must be 1 dimensional error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a pandas series (named "clusters") which somewhat looks like:

```
0 [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
1 [[1, 2, 3], [9, 10, 11]]
```

I get this series by converting:  list > dataframe > as_matrix
After processing the matrix I get the series.

I want to access the series by the index which is 0 and 1 here. 
But when I do clusters[0] or clusters[1].

I get an error  **Data must be 1 dimensional error**

I dont know what the issue is here.

Alternatively if loop through this series how do I access the index ?
So if I say:

```
for k in clusters:
      print k
```

I get [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]. But I want to get the index this "[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]" is linked to. How do I get that. I tried k.index but nothing works.

Comment: If I create a series with `s = pd.Series({0 : [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], 1: [[1, 2, 3], [9, 10, 11]]})` then `s[0]` and `s[1]` work fine. Is your Series different somehow?

Comment: @cryptX can you share the result of `print(clusters.index)`

Comment: @shanmuga:  Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64'). I am trying to get the index for the element of linked to index 0  etc.

Comment: @EvanWright I also tried that. Worked for me. My code has lat, long in the similar format which looks like 
`code`
0    [[37.2338, -77.3306], [37.2338, -77.3306]]
1    [[37.5522, -77.4582], [37.5522, -77.4582]]

Comment: output of `clusters.to_json()` might make the situation clearer.

Comment: @AndyHayden: {u'0': [[39.3326, -76.6928], [39.3326, -76.6928], [39.3326, -76.6928], [39.3326, -76.6928]]}  This is what I am getting

Comment: I am generating the series as :  clusters = pd.Series([coordinates[labels == i] for i in xrange(num_clusters)]) .  coordinates here is a matrix

Comment: @AndyHayden I used json and for now I have used that as a hack. But I'll fig out what the issue is with my series.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through items, which iterates with the index label:

```
In [11]: for ind, k in clusters.items():
             print(ind)
0
1
```

---

I think there is something funky with your Series as you ought to be able to access by index:

```
In [12]: clusters[0]
Out[12]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

In [13]: clusters.loc[0]
Out[13]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: Does series have items object ?

Comment: @cryptX it's a Series method: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iteritems.html (I think it works in both python 2 and 3; but perhaps it's `.iteritems`)

Comment: aah ok !! Thanks. I think there is something wrong in my Series.

Answer (score 0):

As for the getting the index you might want to do something like

```
print clusters.index(k)
```

If you do k.index, it won't show you anything.